# Display profile FOS UserBundle + Sonata UserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-user-bundle

I use FOS UserBundle with Sonata Admin/UserBundle, and I wan't to display FOSUserBundle user profile information.

I can access to the localhost/MyWebSite/web/app_dev.php/**profile/edit**, but
I cannot access to localhost/MyWebSite/web/app_dev.php/**profile**

I have this error :

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "**sonata_user_profile_edit**" as such route does not exist.") in SonataUserBundle:Profile:action.html.twig at line 27.

I don't understand why an Sonata user profile route was generate when I'm asking for **FOSUserBundle profile** page

In log file I can see the good rooting message :

*INFO - Matched route "fos_user_profile_show".*

Thank's for your help.

My routting file

```
#FOS USER AND SONATA ADMIN ROUTES
fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /change-password

admin:
    resource: '@SonataAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_admin.xml'
    prefix:   /admin

_sonata_admin:
    resource: .
    type: sonata_admin
    prefix: /admin

soanata_user:
    resource: '@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/admin_security.xml'
    prefix: /admin

sonata_user_impersonating:
    pattern: /
    defaults: { _controller: SonataPageBundle:Page:catchAll }

homepage:
pattern:  /
```

---

**Edit 1 :**
I try some debug verification

When I call Url : localhost/MyWebSite/web/app_dev.php/**profile** the good route *fos_user_profile_show* was find.

Go in the FOS controller

..\vendor\friendsofsymfony\user-bundle\ **FOS** \ **UserBundle**\Controller\ **ProfileController**.php

But after ProfileController *showAction()* function, there is a call to **Sonata UserBundle action.html.twig **

Path : *...\vendor\sonata-project\user-bundle\Resources\views\Profile\action.html.twig*

I don't understand where is my mistake and how it's possible :-(
...\vendor\friendsofsymfony\user-bundle\FOS\UserBundle\Resources\config\routing\profile.xml

```
<!--\vendor\friendsofsymfony\user-bundle\FOS\UserBundle\Resources\config\routing\profile.xml-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<route id="fos_user_profile_show" path="/" methods="GET">
    <default key="_controller">FOSUserBundle:Profile:show</default>
</route>

<route id="fos_user_profile_edit" path="/edit" methods="GET POST">
    <default key="_controller">FOSUserBundle:Profile:edit</default>
</route>
```

...\vendor\sonata-project\user-bundle\Resources\config\routing\sonata_profile_1.xml

```
<routes xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/routing"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/routing http://symfony.com/schema/routing/routing-1.0.xsd">

<route id="fos_user_profile_show" pattern="/">
    <default key="_controller">SonataUserBundle:ProfileFOSUser1:show</default>
    <requirement key="_method">GET</requirement>
</route>

<route id="fos_user_profile_edit_authentication" pattern="/edit-authentication">
    <default key="_controller">SonataUserBundle:ProfileFOSUser1:editAuthentication</default>
</route>

<route id="fos_user_profile_edit" pattern="/edit-profile">
    <default key="_controller">SonataUserBundle:ProfileFOSUser1:editProfile</default>
</route>

<route id="sonata_user_profile_show" pattern="/">
    <default key="_controller">SonataUserBundle:ProfileFOSUser1:show</default>
    <requirement key="_method">GET</requirement>
</route>

<route id="sonata_user_profile_edit_authentication" pattern="/edit-authentication">
    <default key="_controller">SonataUserBundle:ProfileFOSUser1:editAuthentication</default>
</route>

<route id="sonata_user_profile_edit" pattern="/edit-profile">
    <default key="_controller">SonataUserBundle:ProfileFOSUser1:editProfile</default>
</route>
```

Comment: check the xml files @FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml and @SonataAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_admin.xml for the routes. looks some sort of mixup. make sure they don't use the same URLs.

Answer (score 0):

I did not quite figure out the whole "science" behind it yet, as FOS User and Sonata User are the most confusing bundles out there, but this will fix your problem.

Just follow this article:
https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/2-2/doc/reference/profile_edition.html

And also replace this:

```
fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /profile
```

With this:

```
sonata_user_change_password:
    resource: "@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_change_password_1.xml"
    prefix: /profile
```

It is where I stopped so far. The next step would be to figure out what portion do you want to handle using FOS vs. Sonata and design the profile UI/UX. I see that the username & password can be changed in two different places in Profile, which is not pretty.

Use this too, it helps:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/configuration_reference.html